# Get access to node element from Child component in Parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a Parent component which render Child component. My Child component render two other components through "children" property.

So, it looks like:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  input = React.createRef();
  render() {
   return (
     <Form setRef={this.input}>
       <Label />
       <Input />
     </Form>
   )
  }
}

class Form extends Component {
  render() {
   const { setRef } = this.props;
   const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
    setRef,
 });
});
   return (
      <>
       <form>
         {children}
       </form>
      </>
    )
  }
}

class Input extends Component {
  render() {
   const { setRef } = this.props;
   return <input ref={setRef} />
  }
}

class Label extends Component {
  render() {
   return <label>Title</label>
  }
}
```

As I've read in one article, I should use "React.cloneElement Top-Level API" to have ability pass props from parent component to childrens without explicitly set property in child component.

The main goal is to focus input on click event and control input node inside my ParentComponent.

The question is: How can I get access to input node in my parent component? Currently, I tried do it like in the code above but it gives me null if I console this.input.current in my ParentComponent.

Comment: as per the React.js documentation of Refs,the Refs are created using React.createRef() and attached to React elements via the ref attribute, in your code you have used attribute setRef in parent component, just a wild guess

Comment: Seems like a forward ref problem, https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html